# how to use IMapTimeDisplay.TimeValue to get current time setting from timeslider in ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, timeslider

Has anyone out there used the IMapTimeDisplay.TimeValue to get the current time from the timeslider control? I cannot figure out how to properly use it.

I am writing some code in VB .net that creates a bar graph (in a dockable window in ArcMap) from some of the attribute values in a polygon feature class. My feature class is time-enabled with an attribute called "Year" and the time slider is visible in ArcMap, but the data I send to the bar graph is not filtered by the current year selected on the slider. So, I need the current time to filter my data with.

I have the following which may not be correct, although it does not throw an error:

```
Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument = TryCast(My.ArcMap.Application.Document, IMxDocument)
Dim pMap As IMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
Dim pMapTimeDisplay As IMapTimeDisplay = pMap
Dim pTimeValue As ITimeValue = pMapTimeDisplay.TimeValue
Dim pTimeExtent As ITimeExtent = TryCast(pTimeValue, ITimeExtent)   'added
```

But, I can't figure out what to do from there. Can anyone help me please? I have searched the internet to the best of my ability.

*Additional information*
I tried this, but it caused an error in ArcMap:

```
Dim currentYear As Integer = pTimeExtent.StartTime.Year
```

The error is "Unhandled exception has occurred..." and "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Yet, I have used pTimeExtent.StartTime.Year successfully in other parts of my code to get the start time of the entire time range using pTimeExtent = pMapTimeDisplay.CurrentTimeExtent.

Comment: You need to recast your ITimeValue as ITimeInstant or ITimeExtent

Comment: I tried recasting ITimeValue as ITimeExtent as so: Dim pTimeExtent As ITimeExtent = TryCast(pTimeValue, ITimeExtent) and then, I tried to get the pTimeExtent.StartTime.Year as well as the pTimeExtent.EndTime.Year, but both of these crashed ArcMap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much playing around with the various properties of the IMapTimeDisplay2 interface, I finally found something that worked. Perhaps this works because my dataset is time-enabled by an attribute called "Year" that has integer year values from 2010 to 2100 in 5 year increments, and I'm only interested in rendering one year at a time, so the "start time" and "end time" of the data displayed in the map are the same. Anyway, I recast my IMapTimeDisplay2.TimeValue to ITimeInstant as so:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument = My.ArcMap.Application.Document
    Dim pMap As IMap = pMxDoc.FocusMap
    Dim pTimeDisplay As IMapTimeDisplay2 = TryCast(pMap, IMapTimeDisplay2)
    Dim pTimeValue As ITimeValue = pTimeDisplay.TimeValue
    Dim pTimeInstant As ITimeInstant = TryCast(pTimeValue, ITimeInstant)
    If pTimeInstant IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim pCTime As ITime = pTimeInstant.Time
        Dim pCYear As Integer = pCTime.Year
        MsgBox(“time instant: " & pCYear)
    End If
End Sub
```

This is just a short bit of code to see if I could get just the current year that the time slider was on. It worked fine.